# Get Windows 7 to Stop Grouping Search Results by Immediate Parent Folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, search, sorting

Searching in Windows 7 is frustrating, inconsistent, and too different from in XP. One of the most egregious problems is that it insists on grouping search results by the immediate parent of items. That is, in the `Folder` column, instead of simply listing the directory path that the item is stored in, Windows 7 lists the immediate parent, and then puts the rest of the path in parentheses.

This behavior is baffling at best since it has little, if any, practical application, but more importantly, it breaks sorting on the `Folder` column as shown below.

Is there a way to get Windows 7 to knock it off?

---

Correct Folder-sorting in XP:

[image: Correct Folder-sorting in XP]

Incorrect Folder-sorting in 7

[image: Incorrect Folder-sorting in 7]

Comment: I'm at work on XP now, but I believe there an alternative column you can add called "Path" or "FullPath", which acts like Folder in XP. It is then useful to have both options - whereas XP only sorted by path. Now try to search for files that contains two words (AND, not OR). Mwahahah.

Comment: Actually, I had already looked for another column like *In Folder* *Contained*, etc., but found none (and didn’t feel like searching through all the default columns that 7 includes). You’re right; there is one called *Path* – **not** *Folder Path* - that does that. If you re-post this as an answer, I can accept it (and check out your problem). `:-D`

Comment: Done, thanks. As for the AND search terms, pretty certain there's no solution.

Comment: Woah, I just noticed that in the Windows-7 screenshot, the columns are messed up; *Size* is empty and placed in *Folder*, and *Folder* is placed in a non-existent column! What the heck‽

Comment: Weird. Might be related to a bug in the XP-classic layout (with the checkbox and all), instead of the default Aero style.

Comment: I’m able to reproduce it by pressing Ctrl+Numpad+ to auto-resize the columns. I can see the *Size* header shrinking and the *Folder* header shifting along with it, but the columns in the list-control remain unaffected; only the headers auto-resize (I’d bet that it is a Win7 bug and happens in Aero as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can right-click on your column titles and add one called "Path". Sorting search results on this column will work like it did in Windows XP.

Comment: Now it would be amazing if that change could somehow be made permanent.